How do I fix my code, it is returning an empty list?
I am scraping an ecommerce website and its returning an empty list
This is the code I wrote.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/'

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/126.0.0.0'}

r = requests.get('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/35/japanese-whisky')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all("li", class_="product-grid__item")
print(productlist)

this is the result I am getting
[]


Print out soup and you'll see the problem. They're using detection to prevent what you're trying to do.

As mentioned in the comment, you are getting blocked. However, you can get around this by using Playwright.
Install the playwright package and then install Chromium.
pip3 install playwright
playwright install chromium

The code below will grab the names and URL paths for the products selected via the CSS you provided.
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/35/japanese-whisky"

playwright = sync_playwright().start()

browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=2000)
context = browser.new_context(
    viewport={"width": 1280, "height": 900}
)

page = context.new_page()

page.goto(URL)

page.locator(".product-grid__list").wait_for()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), 'lxml')

for product in soup.select("li.product-grid__item > a"):
    name = product.select_one("p.product-card__name").text
    url = product["href"]
    print(f"{name} | {url}")

page.close()

If you don't want to see the browser window then set headless=True.
Sample output:
Hibiki Harmony | /p/29388/hibiki-harmony
Nikka Coffey Grain Whisky | /p/23928/nikka-coffey-grain-whisky
Hakushu Distiller's Reserve | /p/23771/hakushu-distillers-reserve
Yamazaki 12 Year Old | /p/2940/yamazaki-12-year-old
Suntory Toki | /p/36362/suntory-toki
Yamazaki Distiller's Reserve | /p/23772/yamazaki-distillers-reserve
Ichiro's Malt MWRMizunara Wood Reserve | /p/46186/ichiros-malt-mwr-mizunara-wood-reserve
Chichibu Red Wine Cask 2023 | /p/80949/chichibu-red-wine-cask-2023
Kanosuke Single Malt | /p/72178/kanosuke-single-malt
Hibiki 21 Year Old | /p/10134/hibiki-21-year-old
Fuji Single Malt Whisky | /p/72434/fuji-single-malt-whisky
Yamazaki 18 Year OldGift Box | /p/81705/yamazaki-18-year-old-gift-box
The Chita Distiller's Reserve | /p/44794/the-chita-distillers-reserve
Yoichi Single Malt | /p/32761/yoichi-single-malt
Kaiyo Mizunara Oak Cask Strength | /p/45367/kaiyo-mizunara-oak-cask-strength
Mars Tsunuki2022 Edition | /p/71682/mars-tsunuki-2022-edition
Kanosuke Single Malt 2022 Limited Edition | /p/71032/kanosuke-single-malt-2022-limited-edition
Nikka Miyagikyo PeatedDiscovery Series 2021 | /p/61449/nikka-miyagikyo-peated-discovery-series-2021
Miyagikyo Single Malt | /p/32762/miyagikyo-single-malt
Yamazaki 12 Year Old100th Anniversary | /p/71847/yamazaki-12-year-old-100th-anniversary
Hakushu 12 Year Old | /p/2922/hakushu-12-year-old
Chichibu The Peated 2022 | /p/70564/chichibu-the-peated-2022
Kanosuke Double Distillery Blended Whisky | /p/81245/kanosuke-double-distillery-blended-whisky
Kanosuke Hioki Pot Still | /p/81244/kanosuke-hioki-pot-still

